# NetBeans 8.2 Cannot "Step In"

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

Good evening all!
So my current situation is I have installed NetBeans 8.2 with JDK 8u241 on a Windows 8.1 x64 OS. I'm am currently trying to learn how to use the debugging tool. So currently when I set a Breakpoint on one of the lines and click on the debugger I get:

```
Listening on javadebug
User program running
Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint Grades.java : 23, reason: No source root found for URL 'file:/C:/Users/sntaf_000/Documents/Projects/Grades/src/grades/Grades.java'. Verify the setup of project sources.
Invalid LineBreakpoint Grades.java : 23
LineBreakpoint TravelCosts.java : 20 successfully submitted.
Breakpoint hit at line 20 in class travelcosts.TravelCosts by thread main.
Thread main stopped at TravelCosts.java:20.
```

at the end in the Debugger Console. If I try to proceed with "step into" another tab will open up Next to my program called *Scanner.java* and I get a lot of comments and the entirety of it is completely gray.

If I look to the left pane from the program I can see that it seems this is coming from the libraries>JDK 1.8 (default)>rt.jar

Underneath in the navigator is what looks like a new inner class titled *Scanner* :: Iterator ,Closeable

If I close it out I still cannot get the debugger to go to the next line of code because it does it again. I just want to step into the next line of code. which isn't happening. Please assist?

What's weird is in the error shown above I There is the line that states:
Invalid LineBreakpoint Grades.java : 23
This is from a program I tried earlier and that's when I first notice the debugger was not working for me. TravelCosts is an entirely different program.

I am very new to Java and NetBeans and I'm very sorry for the long explanation but I'm also a very detail oriented in explanation as I find it's more assistive. Thank you very much for your assistance in advance.

---

Okay so I figured out what the issues was as far as : Invalid LineBreakpoint Grades.java : 23. Apparently the debugger was still "connected" in some way to a previous project and I found the line contributing to it via: Window>Debugging>Breakpoints then deleting the breakpoint in the run tab at the bottom... BUT I'M STILL GETTING THE SCANNER TAB =D

---

Also if I look in the Window>Documents I saw this: java/util/Scanner.java in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\src.zip (read-only) I'm not sure if this is helpful but I'm wondering if Maybe the .zip file needs to be extracted?

Comment: Don't provide updates to your question as comments. Instead, directly edit your question, then delete the comments.

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to this environment and had been struggling and frustrated so much with trying to accomplish something that I did not read how to update my question.